# how do i create a composite key that comprises a foreign key with code first?

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first, ef4-code-only, ef-code-first

I am using EF4 code first and want to generate a composite key which is made of a class property and foreign key. I have two classes: Order and Company. The Order class holds a reference but this will not necessarily be unique between companies. So I intend to use a composite key made up of Reference and Company.CompanyId.

I have tried using the following to set it but I get an error message "Key expression is not valid".

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(o => new { o.Reference, o.Company.CompanyId });
```

I have also tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(o => new { o.Reference, o.Company });
```

and this fails.

these are my classes:

```
public class Order
{
   public string Reference { get; set; }
   public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

As Antony Highsky mentioned, you can only use scalar properties in the key. 
So, you will need to add a foreign key (scalar property) to the **Order** class and associate it with the navigation property **Company** as shown below:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [RelatedTo(ForeignKey = "CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And then create the composite key using the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(o => new { o.Reference, o.CompanyId });
```

Note that data annotations (RelatedTo attribute) were introduced with the Entity Framework CTP 3. For another option that only uses data annotations instead of HasKey method, see this post:

- http://www.luisrocha.net/2010/11/creating-composite-keys-using-code.html

Answer (score 1):

One thing that doesn't look quite right is your use of the non-generic version of ICollection. Try this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

modelBuilder.Entity().HasKey(o =>o.Reference );
modelBuilder.Entity().HasKey(o =>o.CompanyId );

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e0010ecf-e82b-4804-b05e-250eda26bf11),  only scalar properties are allowed in the key. Navigation properties are not.